# How to make NUnit assertion failures show line numbers for C++?

Tags: c++, nunit

When I run NUnit tests against my C++ code and an assertion fails, I don't get line numbers for where the failure occurs.

Sample Method:

```
[Test]
void testMethod()
{
    Assert::Fail("test comment");
}
```

Sample output:

> [nunit2] Failures:
>
> [nunit2] 1) namespace.SomeTest.testMethod: test comment
>
> [nunit2]    at namespace.SomeTest.testMethod()

Similar output (also without line numbers) is generated for any assertion failure.

When looking at my output, how do I get line number information for which line caused the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that you are building your classes with Debug information (PDB).

The Assert framework basically throws an exception when the assert fails and the exception captures a StackTrace. The stack trace gets it's line numbers from the PDB file associated with the executable.